# How to create a scrollpane on fxml using controller

Tags: javafx, fxml, scrollpane

I  would  like  to  create  a  scrollpane  and  button  from  the  controller  and display it  in  fxml, is  that  possible? This  my  code  but  it  doesn't  work

controller

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;


public class controller {

     ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
     Button button = new Button("My Button");


    public void initialize() {
        button.setPrefSize(400, 300);
        scrollPane.setContent(button);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
    }
}
```

main

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ui.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("ScrollPane Demo ");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(parent,600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
     }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);}
    }
```

fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox id="vbox" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controller">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: why to you want to mix? Unrelated: java naming conventions, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your vbox in your controller, like this:

```
@FXML
private VBox vbox;
```

After that, add your scrollpane to your vbox's children:

```
vbox.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
```

Note that, you not added your button to your scrollpane's content, so your scrollpane is currently empty!

Edit: why you want to add nodes via fxml and from code too? Use this solution if it is really necessary, anyway use fxml to build your UI.